# PHP & SELECT how to?

Tags: php, sql

I want to show what the user($pusername) have been posted, in member_film, member_meetups, member_tutorials.. And then if e.g the user have 2 columns with his username, i want to display the "navn" from the same column. Same with title on member_tutorials, and meetup on member_meetups.

An example on how i want it to look like:

Your posts: (which as i want, checks the three table if there's any columns with the user's username in "username" column.)

My new video, its so good (navn, which is from member_film)

My boring meetup with my parents (title, which is from member_meetup)

My great great video!(navn, which is from member_film)

Comment: Please rephrase and restructure your question to be more clear. In it's current form it is impossible to answer it. Post relevant code snippets and database schemas as well, please.

Comment: I think you'll have to use separate queries for the three tables.

Comment: thats what i thought tomba.. but maybe there were another idea to do this..

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess what your question is. And this is procedural style, not OOP.

```
// Make sure you've connected to the db
$pusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($pusername);
$query = mysqli_query($CONNECTION,"SELECT * FROM `database`.`member_film` WHERE `user` = '{$pusername}'");
$results = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
print_r($results);
```

Try that, fiddle with it, and it should start to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a view, it's possible you could do this.  A view is basically an imaginery table that's built out of another query.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html